# My proof that $4$ either divides $n^2$ or $n^2 − 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am attempting to prove the following statement

> Prove that if n is any integer then 4 either divides n^2 or n^2 − 1

I have started with the case of n = 2k

```
Consider the case n = 2k

  n = 2k
  n^2 = 4k^2
⇒ n = 4k

∴ 4 divides n^2 as there is some integer k in which n = k
```

Would this be considered as a correct proof for the first case here? Is there any additions I should make?

I also attempted case 2, where n = 2k+1, however I am less sure of the direction I have taken this and is incomplete, so some advice on this would also be appreciated.

```
Consider the case n = 2k+1

n       = 2k+1
n^2     = (2k+1)^2
n^2     = 4k^2 + 1
n^2 - 1 = 4k^2
```

Comment: the second case should be $n^2=4k^2+4k+1$ but other than that it is fine

Comment: Note that $(2k+1)^2=4k(k+1)+1$ and $k(k+1)$ is divisible by $2$ - this isn't your question, I know, but it is sometimes useful to know that the square of an odd number is one more than a multiple of $8$ (and not just $4$).

Comment: In the first case, where did the last two lines, $n=4k$ and $n=k$, come from?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Alternate proof: $$\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{4}={n\choose 2}\cdot{n+1\choose 2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case $n=2k$, then $$n^2=4k^2$$
$$\therefore \space 4|n^2 \space \text{that is if $n$ is even then $n^2$ is divisible by $4$}$$

For the case $n=2k+1$ we have $$n^2-1=(2k+1)^2-1=(2k)^2+2k+2k+1-1=4k^2+4k=4(k^2+k)$$
$$\therefore \space 4|(n^2-1) \space \text{that is if $n$ is odd then $n^2-1$ is divisible by $4$}$$

Since all integers are of the form $2k$ or $2k+1$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for the first case is fine, except for the very last few words:

`∴ 4 divides n^2 as there is some integer k in which n = k`

You have already declared before that `n=2k`. To now refer to `k` again and claim that `n=k` is confusing at best, and irrelevant. What you want to say is:

`∴ 4 divides n^2 as there is some integer m for which n^2 = 4m.`

And in fact your argument shows that this integer is `m=k^2`.

For the second case, you are on the right track. But you make a mistake in your algebra:

```
n^2     = (2k+1)^2
n^2     = 4k^2 + 1
```

This step is wrong. The distributive rule gives:

`(2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1`

You should verify this. It now follows that

`n^2 - 1 = 4k^2 + 4k`

Now you would like to conclude, as before, by saying that

`∴ 4 divides n^2-1 as there is some integer m for which n^2-1 = 4m.`

Do you see why? What is this integer `m`?

Answer (score -1):

Here's another simple proof using parity. $[$Actually the same thing what @Ares did, but not taking the form of $2k$ or $(2k + 1)$$]$

Suppose $n$ is even, then $2|n$, which implies $4|n^2$, so $n$ has to be odd.

Now if $n$ is odd, then  note that $(n^2 - 1) = (n + 1)(n - 1)$ . Here in this case both $(n + 1)$ and $(n - 1)$ will be even as $n$ is odd.
So $2|(n+1)$ , $2|(n-1)$ which implies that :-  $$(2*2)|(n+1)(n-1)$$
$$\rightarrow 4|(n^2 - 1)$$

In other words, $4|n^2$ if $n$ is even, else $4|(n^2 - 1)$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?